# See if Alfresco Server is available

Tags: jakarta-ee, alfresco, cmis

I am working with Alfresco and sometimes the server is down for low space or other problem , the thing is with my serverURL i want to check if he is available (Alfresco Server) i thought to make a ping but the adresse is to complexe for a simple ping ex : http://127.0.0.1:8084/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom 
I am working in a J2EE Project

Comment: Would `/alfresco/service/api/server` work? Or do you need to check that writes succeed?

Comment: I tried it and it said java.net.UnknownHostException i used http://127.0.0.1/alfresco/service/api/server

Comment: You need to give the port, and either give the public IP of the machine OR run the check from the machine itself

Comment: I tried it with the port and it is the same **java.net.UnknownHostException**

Comment: Without knowing the code you're using to do the fetch it's hard to help you, but most likely you're stuffing that bit up...

Comment: Thank you @Gagrvarr it is the right path to see if it's working i will post the answer (the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i want to say that the part of the answer where given by @Gagravarr

```
public void pingADR() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8084/alfresco/service/api/server";
String status = getStatus(url);
System.out.println(url + "\t\tStatus:" + status);
}
```

and to see if it's available

```
public static String getStatus(String url) throws IOException {

    String result = "";
    try {
        URL siteURL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL
                .openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (code == 200) {
            result = "Green";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = "->Red<-";
    }
    return result;
}
```

I found this answer in a very helpful web site, Hope that will help other people